# Some statements about Elementary Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G_{1},._{1}),(G_{2},._{2}),(G_{3},._{3}),...,(G_{n},._{n})$ be groups.
Then $(G_{1}\times G_{2}\times ... \times G_{n},._{G}) = (G,._{G})$ is a group with the definition of $._{G}$ being $(x_{1},...,x_{n})._{G}(y_{1},...,y_{n})=(x_{1}._{1}y_{1},...,x_{n}._{n}y_{n})$

Now consider the function:

$f_{i}:G_{i} \rightarrow G$

$x_{i} \mapsto (e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{i-1},x_{i},e_{i+1},...,e_{n})$

I have already proved that $f_{i}(G_{i}) = G_{i}^{o}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I also have proved 
$\prod_{i} G_{i}^{o} = G$

But I'm having trouble with the following statement:
$G_{i}^{o} \cap \prod_{i\neq j} G_{j}^{o} =  \{e_{G} \} $

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Look at $G_i^o$ and $G_j^o$ for $j\neq i$. Suppose $(x_1,...,x_n)\in G_i^o\cap G_j^o$. Then $(x_1,...,x_n)\in G_i^o$ implies $(x_1,...,x_n)=(e_1,...e_{i-1},x_i,e_{i+1},...,e_n)$ and similarly $(x_1,...,x_n)\in G_j^o$ implies $(x_1,...,x_n)=...$ Then compare these two results.